# Best practice in filling missing records in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

The problem:

A dataframe df has records for customer_id and month. The monthly data is a contiguous period over several years. The data has, however, gaps - for some customers for some months no records exist. These missing records have to be "replaced" by dummy records holding None for all values apart from the customer_id and the month (customer_id and month are, essentially, a primary key for that dataframe as one and only one record should exist per customer and per month).

Here is a snapshot:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'cust_id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
                 'month' : [200010,200011,200012,200101,200102,200103,200010,200011,200012,200101,200103],
                 'volume' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12],
                 'num_transactions': [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]})
```

In this particular snapshot customer 2 does not have a record for '200102' (February 2001).

My first idea is to solve it like this:

```
df = df.set_index(['customer_id', 'month'])
all_months = frozenset(df.customer_id.unique())
all_customers = frozenset(df.customer_id.unique())

dummy_records = df.loc[(None, None)] # empty dataframe with same index & columns
dummy_record = [None] * number_of_features

for i in all_months:
   for j in all_customers:
      if !((i,j) in df.index):
          dummy_records.loc[(i,j)] = dummy_record

df = pd.concatenate([df, dummy_records])
```

But my hunch is that this is not elegant. Can you suggest something better?

Comment: what is it that you want none replace: max, min or other..